# Why array_diff() compares two different arrays as same and returns empty result?

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have this code:

```
$a1 = array(31001);
$a2 = array(31001, 31002);
$diff = array_diff($a1, $a2);
var_dump($diff);
```

I was expecting that array_diff will return `array(0 => 31002)` according to PHP documentation:

> Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not
>   present in any of the other arrays.

However posted code returns empty array. Anyone can explain me why is this happening and how to get correct result ?

Here is [PHPfiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rqe-tjb).

Thanks for any help or helpful hints.

Comment: Funny try `$diff = array_diff($a2, $a1);` ^^

Comment: This returns exactly what is in array 1 and not in array 2 (nothing then).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the documentation exactly. The set of values that are present in `$a1` and not present in `$a2` is empty: `$a1` just contains one element (`31001`), which is also present in `$a2`.

You want to get all values that are present in `$a2`, but not in `$a1`, so you have to switch the order of the arrays, you pass to `array_diff()`:

```
$diff = array_diff($a2, $a1);
```

Comment: Thanks, this brings a bell. I thought that order of the arrays doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

**try this, it will work**

```
$diff = array_diff($a2, $a1);
```

**it will give**

```
Array
(
[1] => 31002
)
```

**but when you try**

```
$a1 = array(31001);
$a2 = array(31002, 31001);
$diff = array_diff($a2, $a1);
```

**it will give**

```
Array
  (
 [0] => 31002
 )
```

**array_diff  will return array(0 => 31002), in this condition only, it is due to index location of elements**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 $a1 = array(31001);
 $a2 = array(31002);
 $diff = array_diff($a1, $a2);

 var_dump($diff)

?>
```

add in $a2=array() one element